# bash/python script to retrieve nodes with given tag property

Tags: python, bash

The document.xml file looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document version="4">
    <tool version="21.4"/>
    <notes>
        <note id="minor" message="dont forget">
            <place file="path/to/fileA" line="81"/>
        </note>
        <note id="major" message="quite well">
            <place file="path/to/fileB" line="11"/>
            <place file="path/to/fileC" line="67"/>
        </note>
        <!-- ... -->
        <note id="medium" message="keep going">
            <place file="path/to/fileF" line="789"/>
            <place file="path/to/fileA" line="91"/>
            <!-- ... -->
            <place file="path/to/fileK" line="6"/>
        </note>
    </notes>
</document>
```

I need a script that could "grep" the above based on 'file' attribute of `<note>` tag.

For example:

prompt$ xmlgrep "path/to/fileA" document.xml

would result in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document version="4">
    <tool version="21.4"/>
    <notes>
        <note id="minor" message="dont forget">
            <place file="path/to/fileA" line="81"/>
        </note>
        <note id="medium" message="keep going">
            <place file="path/to/fileF" line="789"/>
            <place file="path/to/fileA" line="91"/>
            <place file="path/to/fileK" line="6"/>
        </note>
    </notes>
</document>
```

Could You please suggest me some ?elegant? way to achieve it?

best regards

Comment: This kinda looks like a job for a parameterized xslt, rather than python or bash, per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following code works well but not a well formatted xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys
path = sys.argv[1]
xml_file = sys.argv[2]
tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()
notes = root.find('notes')
for note in notes:
    found_any_path = False
    for place in note[:]:
        if place.attrib['file'] == path:
            found_any_path = True
    else:
        if not found_any_path:
            notes.remove(note)

print ET.tostring(root, encoding="UTF-8", method="xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use an xml parser instead of regular expressions for this. For example:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse('./doc.xml')
notes = doc.findall('notes')
for notes_el in notes:
    note = notes_el.findall('note')
    for note_el in note:
        found = False
        for p in note_el.iter('place'):
            if p.attrib['file'] == 'path/to/fileA':
                found = True
        if not found:
            notes_el.remove(note_el)
print etree.tostring(doc)
```